# Error while upgrading kernel

Tags: 14.04, apt, upgrade, kernel

I am trying to upgrade the kernel:

```
(synaptic:22238): GLib-CRITICAL **: g_child_watch_add_full: assertion 'pid > 0' failed
Väljer tidigare ej valt paket linux-image-3.13.0-30-lowlatency.
(Läser databasen ... 331247 filer och kataloger installerade.)
Preparing to unpack .../linux-image-3.13.0-30-lowlatency_3.13.0-30.54_amd64.deb ...
Done.
Unpacking linux-image-3.13.0-30-lowlatency (3.13.0-30.54) ...
Ställer in linux-image-3.13.0-30-lowlatency (3.13.0-30.54) ...
Running depmod.
update-initramfs: deferring update (hook will be called later)
Examining /etc/kernel/postinst.d.
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/apt-auto-removal 3.13.0-30-lowlatency /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-30-lowlatency
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/dkms 3.13.0-30-lowlatency /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-30-lowlatency
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools 3.13.0-30-lowlatency/boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-30-lowlatency
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-30-lowlatency

gzip: stdout: No space left on device
E: mkinitramfs failure cpio 141 gzip 1
update-initramfs: failed for /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-30-lowlatency with 1.
run-parts: /etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools exited with return code 1
Failed to process /etc/kernel/postinst.d at /var/lib/dpkg/info/linux-image-3.13.0-30-lowlatency.postinst line 1025.
dpkg: error processing package linux-image-3.13.0-30-lowlatency (--configure):
underprocessen installerade post-installation-skript gav felkod 2
Fel uppstod vid hantering:
linux-image-3.13.0-30-lowlatency
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
Ett paket misslyckades att installeras. Försöker återhämta:
Ställer in linux-image-3.13.0-30-lowlatency (3.13.0-30.54) ...
Running depmod.
update-initramfs: deferring update (hook will be called later)
The link /initrd.img is a dangling linkto /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-30-lowlatency
vmlinuz(/boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-30-lowlatency) points to /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-30-lowlatency
 (/boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-30-lowlatency) -- doing nothing at /var/lib/dpkg/info/linux-image-3.13.0-30-lowlatency.postinst line 491.
Examining /etc/kernel/postinst.d.
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/apt-auto-removal 3.13.0-30-lowlatency /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-30-lowlatency
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/dkms 3.13.0-30-lowlatency /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-30-lowlatency
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools 3.13.0-30-lowlatency /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-30-lowlatency
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-30-lowlatency

gzip: stdout: No space left on device
E: mkinitramfs failure cpio 141 gzip 1
update-initramfs: failed for /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-30-lowlatency with 1.
run-parts: /etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools exited with return code 1
Failed to process /etc/kernel/postinst.d at /var/lib/dpkg/info/linux-image-3.13.0-30-lowlatency.postinst line 1025.
dpkg: error processing package linux-image-3.13.0-30-lowlatency (--configure):
underprocessen installerade post-installation-skript gav felkod 2
Fel uppstod vid hantering:
linux-image-3.13.0-30-lowlatency
```

Output from df:

```
/dev/sda6       62862260  10919472     48742840  19% /
none                   4         0            4   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
udev             4050264         4      4050260   1% /dev
tmpfs             812972      1544       811428   1% /run
none                5120         0         5120   0% /run/lock
none             4064860         0      4064860   0% /run/shm
none              102400        16       102384   1% /run/user
/dev/sda5         115891     80626        29070  74% /boot
/dev/sda7      824152568 142718332    639562980  19% /home
```

Did the kernel size increased much between 3.13.0-24 and 3.13.0-27. I got trouble when trying to install the automatic upgrade. I have two kernels installed:

- linux-image-3.13.0.24-generic
- linux-image-3.13-0-24-lowlatency

Comment: Could you post the result of `df -h` from your system ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No space left on device.
It seems that /boot partition has no more space to install kernel.
Try to remove any old linux-images.
1. Define which kernel you're using. type in console  `uname -r` so by mistake not remove this kernel. And use synaptic to remove old kernels in sections kernel and ..

Comment: I run out of space. I removed the generic kernel. Perhaps I should increase the size of /boot

Comment: What is the size of the partition do you have?

Comment: The size is 120 M

Comment: The minimum size if you don't plan to upgrade is 100mb.
The recommended size is 300MB-500MB.
Personally i use 200mb and that's enough.

Probably you can use live cd/usb and gparted to increase/extend size of /boot partition.

Just leave one of those kernels (linux-image-3.13.0.24-generic linux-image-3.13-0-24-lowlatency) which is better for your performance and remove another one with command `sudo apt-get remove`

Comment: But remember to find out which kernel currently used and leave it. `uname -r`